# How do I properly use of UnitOfWorks, Repository and Dispose

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-of-work

I have taken over the coding of a software and the way it is currently done, I am not sure that the Dispose() method in the UnitOfWorks is getting called. I have noticed that my SQL service tends to stop after a while (days) saying that all connections are being used up.

I would like to know if the below code is properly done and if not, how I can go about rectifying so that it calls the dispose() method.

**UnitOfWorks.cs**

```
public class UnitOfWorks 
{
    private KaprukaEntities context;
    private GenericRepository<Transaction> transactionRepository;
    private bool disposed;

    public GenericRepository<Transaction> TransactionRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.transactionRepository == null)
                this.transactionRepository = new GenericRepository<Transaction>(this.context);
            return this.transactionRepository;
        }
    }

    public UnitOfWorks(KaprukaEntities entities)
    {
        this.context = entities;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        this.context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed && disposing)
            this.context.Dispose();
        this.disposed = true;
    }
    public interface IDisposable
    {
        void Dispose();
    }
}
```

The UnitOfWorks is getting called by a service class.

**TransactionService.cs**

```
public class TransactionService
{
    private UnitOfWorks _unitOfWork;
    private KaprukaEntities entities;

    public TransactionService(UnitOfWorks unitOfWork)
    {
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this.entities = new KaprukaEntities();
    }

    public bool Add(Transaction entity)
    {
        this._unitOfWork.TransactionRepository.Add(entity);
        this._unitOfWork.Save();
        var er = this.entities.GetValidationErrors();
        return true;
    }

    public bool Update(Transaction entity)
    {
        this._unitOfWork.TransactionRepository.Update(entity);
        this._unitOfWork.Save();
        return true;
    }

    public bool Delete(Transaction entity)
    {
        this._unitOfWork.TransactionRepository.Delete(entity);
        this._unitOfWork.Save();
        return true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Transaction> GetAll()
    {
        return this._unitOfWork.TransactionRepository.GetAll();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Transaction> GetAll(Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> filter, Func<IQueryable<Transaction>, IOrderedQueryable<Transaction>> orderBy, string includeProperties)
    {
        return this._unitOfWork.TransactionRepository.Get(filter, orderBy, includeProperties);
    }
}
```

The way this is getting called is as follows:

There is a file named updateTransaction.aspx and in its code behind, the code calls the service as such:

**updateTransaction.aspx**

```
TransactionService TransServ = new TransactionService(new UnitOfWorks(new KaprukaEntities()));
var TransDetails = TransServ.GetAll(x => x.TransactionID == intTID, null, "").SingleOrDefault();
```

I can't see any code to close or dispose anything.

Comment: Not enough relevant code. Who controls the lifetime of your objects? A IoC container? How long does the `TransactionService` live? Who _should_ dispose the repository?

Comment: Didn't the world move on from the repository pattern for EF. anyway this comment is off topic

Comment: What's the reason of this `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` call? In this kind of code it shouldn't be necessary at all to tamper with garbage collection.

Comment: Thank you for that. I shall get rid of that line.

Comment: Why do you have interface `IDisposable`? Is this your own take on currently existing interface that you don't even implement or what is going on here? Do you actually wrap your calls in `using`? Do you implement `IDisposable` interface?

Comment: If you are using some DI container for injection - most of them take care of disposing the injected elements as well

Comment: even though IDisposable seem to be there, I can't see it being used. There is not code anywhere that is calling it    using

Comment: no DI container for injection used.

Answer (score 0):

Your transactionservice constructor creates an extra db context, when one is already in the unit of work class:

```
  this.entities = new KaprukaEntities();
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I didn't notice that. Great pick up.